# Can't get a larger piece of code to loop after it's done running in Python

Tags: python

I wrote some code to ask for input and give a response based on that input. after that I ask if the user wants to run it again, when answered with ja (the Dutch word for yes, I also added other things like for example the word sure), It's supposed to run the entire program again. If it receives anything other than yes, the program stops.

The program works perfectly fine, but after repeating it once, instead of asking if the user wants to try again, it stops.

Why is this and what can I do to fix this?

```
naam = input("Wat is je naam?\n")

 if naam == "insert name here":
    print("You're right")
    time.sleep(0.25)
 elif naam == "insert name here":
    print("You're right")
    time.sleep(0.25)
 elif naam == "insert name here":
    print("You're right")
    time.sleep(0.25)
 elif naam == "insert name here":
    print("You're right")
    time.sleep(0.25)
 elif naam == "insert name here":
    print("You're right")
    time.sleep(0.25)
 elif naam == "insert name here":
    print("You're right")
    time.sleep(0.25)
 elif naam == "insert name here":
    time.sleep(0.25)
    print("You're right")
 else:
    print("Sorry, try again.")
terugnaarboven()

time.sleep(0.25)

opnieuw = input("Wil je het nog eens doen?\n")
if opnieuw == "ja":
    terugnaarboven()
    time.sleep(0.25)
elif opnieuw == "Ja":
    terugnaarboven()
    time.sleep(0.25)
elif opnieuw == "Zekers":
    terugnaarboven()
    time.sleep(0.25)
elif opnieuw == "Zeker":
    terugnaarboven()
    time.sleep(0.25)
elif opnieuw == "zeker":
    terugnaarboven()
    time.sleep(0.25)
elif opnieuw == "graag":
    terugnaarboven()
    time.sleep(0.25)
elif opnieuw == "Graag":
    terugnaarboven()
    time.sleep(0.25)
elif opnieuw == "Oui":
    time.sleep(0.25)
    terugnaarboven()
elif opnieuw == "Oui":
    time.sleep(0.25)
    terugnaarboven()
else:
    print("Prima!")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Afsluiten...\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: There are no loop statements like "for" or "while".

Answer (score 0):

If you would like your script to run in a continuous loop, you should considering putting your code in a while loop. Possible place your code within a "while True:" if you would like the program to keep running.

Otherwise, if you wanted it to have a conditional check prior such as "ja", check using an if statement prior to running the loop!

`if(input == "ja"):
    #Your Code`

or

```
while input == "ja":
#Your Code
if(input == "stop")
    break
```

Comment: i have tried using a while loop, the only problem is that it repeats the first part of the  code indefinitely after the user types 'ja'. I want it to also repeat the part where it asks  the user if he/she wants to try again. ("Wil je het nog een keer doen?" means "Want to try again?" in Dutch).

Answer (score 0):

if u want the program to run endlessly until user input is for example exit
your code may look like the below example:

```
while True:
    x = input("Wat is je naam?\n")
    if x == 'exit':
        break
    else:
        ...... put your repeatable code here
```

You have too many if statements, change them with only one if:

```
first_list = ['name1', 'another name', 'example', 'go_on', 'give_me_more']
if naam.lower() in first_list:
    print("You're right")
    time.sleep(0.25)
else:
    print("Sorry, try again.")
```

Use naam.lower if the user input is naan ='YES'. naam.lower =  'yes'

Example:

```
opnieuw = 'ja' --> opnieuw.lower() = 'ja'
opnieuw = 'Ja' --> opnieuw.lower() = 'ja'
opnieuw = 'Zeker' --> opnieuw.lower() = 'zeker'
```

Now that u can change all inputs into lower u make a list of low names:

```
second_list = ['ja', 'zeker', 'zekers', 'oui', 'graag']
```

and u eliminate if again into one:

```
if opnieuw in second_list:
    terugnaarboven()
    time.sleep(0.25)
else:
    print("Prima!")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Afsluiten...\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.exit()
```

Your program now should look like the one below....

```
while True:
    naam = input("Wat is je naam?\n")
    if naam.lower() == 'exit':
        break
    else:
        first_list = ['name1', 'another name', 'example', 'go_on', 'give_me_more']
        second_list = ['ja', 'zeker', 'zekers', 'oui', 'graag']
        if naam.lower() in first_list:
            print("You're right")
            time.sleep(0.25)
        else:
            print("Sorry, try again.")
        terugnaarboven()
        time.sleep(0.25)
        opnieuw = input("Wil je het nog eens doen?\n")
        if opnieuw in second_list:
            terugnaarboven()
            time.sleep(0.25)
         else:
             print("Prima!")
             time.sleep(0.5)
             print("Afsluiten...\n")
             time.sleep(1)
             sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'm a beginner though and it's a bit overwhelming atm XD. I'll look through (and try to understand) and I'll get back to you afterwards.